# PowerBI - Conditional Column exact match

Tags: powerbi, conditional-statements, match, powerquery

I have a column below 'Action' which I want to derive two conditional columns from 'Informal' and 'Formal'. If there is an informal in the Action column then I want a 'Y' in the Informal column and likewise if there is a formal then 'Y' in Formal column.

Using PowerQuery with the following I obtained those columns with this:

```
Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Informal", each if Text.Contains([#"Action"], "informal") then "Y" else if Text.Contains([#"Action"], "Informal") then "Y" else null)
```

and

```
Table.AddColumn(#"Added Conditional Column1", "Formal", each if Text.Contains([#"Action"], "formal") then "Y" else if Text.Contains([#"Action"], "Formal") then "Y" else null)
```

However as seen there is duplication of the two columns as formal is in informal. How would I do an exact match (not case sensitive) in the PowerQuery environment. Desired table below example table.

**Dataset**

| Action | Informal | Formal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Informal discussion | Y | Y |
| formal counselling with formal warning |  | Y |
| formal counselling and formal warning |  | Y |
| Welfare check. Informal meeting. | Y | Y |
| Informal counselling and mediation | Y | Y |
| formal counselling second formal warning |  | Y |
| Informal Counselling | Y | Y |
| Formal counselling - formal warning pending mitigations |  | Y |
| Formal meeting, pending mitigations a formal warning |  | Y |
| formal counselling + formal warning. Informal counselling for 2 other respondents pending involvement. | Y | Y |

**Desired table:**

| Action | Informal | Formal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Informal discussion | Y |  |
| formal counselling with formal warning |  | Y |
| formal counselling and formal warning |  | Y |
| Welfare check. Informal meeting. | Y |  |
| Informal counselling and mediation | Y |  |
| formal counselling second formal warning |  | Y |
| Informal Counselling | Y |  |
| Formal counselling - formal warning pending mitigations |  | Y |
| Formal meeting, pending mitigations a formal warning |  | Y |
| formal counselling + formal warning. Informal counselling for 2 other respondents pending involvement. | Y | Y |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that if Informal is Y then Formal has to be null so why not set the formula for Formal to be

```
= if [Informal] ="Y" then null else "Y"
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a trick that I've previously used in VBA when processing sentences.

1. Turn the string of text into a list using the `Text.Split` function with `" "` (space) as separator. It gives you a list of the words in your string.
2. Look into this list for either "formal" or "informal" this the `List.Contains` function.

Here is the bit of code for the column "Formal":

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Formal", each if List.Contains(Text.Split([Action], " "), "formal") then "Y" else null)
```